# Where is the option to add multiple contacts to a group

Tags: groups

I used to be able to do a specific search (such as for contributions in a given period) and then add the results of that search to a new group. The online documentation still refers to it-- "Multiple contacts can be added to a group at once by conducting a search, and then selecting Add Contacts to a Group using the More Actions menu."

I do not see the "more actions menu"--am I missing something? I am not an expert, just a common user. Thanks

Comment: Where did you find that in the docs?  Would be good to get that updated.

Answer (score 7):

'Adding contact's to group' action only appears on the Contact search. If you were doing a Contribution search using Find Contribution, the option won't be available.

You can use the advanced search(CiviCRM >> Search >> Advanced Search), add a contribution filter and do a search.

On the result page, you see an action drop-down called 'Group -Add contacts'

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done via Action from a SearchKit table